# Problems with git merge conflict

Tags: git, merge

I cherry-picked a change from git but during the process I get merge conflicts. I resolved the merge conflict. And committed the change. But after some time I had to hard reset the tree to the change before merge conflict. Now, I cherry-pick the change, I get the merge conflict but the diff on the file does not show it. Is there any way to reset this ?

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What does `git status` report?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by using git rerere command with forget option.

Thanks